# Making a shallow copy of a list of objects

Tags: python, list, copy, shallow-copy

I want to pass a list of objects to a function, get a new modified list but keep the original list unchanged. Like this:

```
class classA():
def __init__(self):
    field1 = 0
    field2 = 0

def func(array):    
    array2 = copy.copy(array) #array[:] gives the same result
    for index, q in enumerate(array):
        if index == 1:
            array2[index].field1 = 5
    return array2

array = [classA(),classA(),classA(),classA()]
array_new = func(array)

print array[1].field1
print array_new[1].field1
```

It prints 5 and 5. Both are changed. I understand that the list itself is shallow copied, but for objects the value of reference is copied (which is why they are tied).

To shallow copy objects as well, I tried this:

```
array2 = [copy.copy(o) for o in array]
```

but it gives me an error:

```
  print array[1].field1
AttributeError: classA instance has no attribute 'field1'
```

What is an easy way to shallow copy the objects inside the list too? Or maybe in general an easier way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `field1` and `field2` instance attributes of `classA`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.field1 = 0
    self.field2 = 0
```

Without prefixing the names with `self.`, `field1` and `field2` will be created as local names that are only available inside the `__init__` method.

---

Also, it looks like you should actually be doing a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) of the list:

```
array2 = copy.deepcopy(array)
```

This will copy both the list object itself as well as all of its items.  Doing a shallow copy will only copy the list object.  From the docs:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
>   original.

Comment: Additionally he or she should be using `self.field1 = 0`, rather than just `field1 = 0`, in his class's `__init__`.

Comment: Your hint to use deep copy doesn't make sense to me, since the author clearly states he wants the shallow copy. Also, shallow copying doesn't copy the list, only its reference.

Comment: @Lawrence - The OP said "keep the original list unchanged" and "What is an easy way to shallow copy the objects inside the list too?"  I took this to mean he wants to copy both the list as well as its items.  As for the other point, let me go clarify that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally misunderstood deep copy and shallow copy, but now I get it

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined it, `field1` is not a field/attribute of the class, it is a local variable in the `__init__()` method.
Instead, the proper way to declare a class field would be like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.field1 = 0
    self.field2 = 0
```